# How can I manage caching in VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, caching

I have a scanned book review VB.Net app that displays two pages (TIF images) at a time and lets the user move forward or backward in the book. The books usually have between 100 and 600 pages and are stored on a network drive. It seems that the TIF images are being cached, because I can go backward in the book a lot lot faster than forward. The Task Manager also shows that the app is using more memory, the further I go in the book.

1. Does the VB app automatically cache files that it reads and displays?
2. If so, how can I reduce the amount of time a file spends in cache?

```
       Public fileNames(10) As String
       Public p As Integer    ' page number of right-hand image
       Public totalImages as Integer
    ' --------
       Dim TNpath as String = "S:\Audit\CP_TN-123456"
       Dim txtFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(TNpath, "*.tif")
       totalImages = txtFiles.Count
       ReDim fileNames(totalImages)
    ' -------- read all fileNames from the Directory
       p = 1  ' when starting a new book, the right-hand image is 1 
    ' -------- moving right in the book
       p = p + 1
       Me.PicBoxRight.Image.Dispose()
       Me.PicBoxRight.Image = Nothing
       imgRight.Dispose()
    ' -------- loading next Right image  
       fileRight = TNpath + "\" + fileNames(p)
       imgRight = Image.FromFile(fileRight)
       Me.PicBoxRight.Image = imgRight
```

Note: Book pages are scanned at 300 DPI and saved in single image TIF files. Each color page is about 25MB and each black/white page is about 8MB. So cache fills up quickly. The app reads files, but does not write files...

Comment: You should probably edit your question with the code you're using to load and display these tiffs.  If I had to guess I would suggest you're probably not disposing of resources properly as users move through the book

Comment: It will be in the Windows file cache until some other program needs the space.

Comment: What does VB call the "Windows file cache"?
What "Import(s)" are required to access it?
How (code-wise) would you set a timeout of 4 seconds for anything in that cache?

Comment: VB calls it nothing. Programs don't control it except in the flags they pass to open files. It is built in to the Windows' kernel. It speeds up all file access. All free memory is used for file caching. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-caching. See *caching behavior* here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea#caching_behavior